# JSON.net unable to figure out to deserialize

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following:

```
[
   {
      "items":[
         {
            "b":1,
            "Q":"data"
         },
         {
            "b":2,
            "Q":"more data"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "seconds_ago":1
   }
]
```

I try to deserialize into a C# object using

```
   public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public Item[] items { get; set; }
        public int seconds_ago { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int b { get; set; }
        public string Q { get; set; }
    }

public void test()
{
    Rootobject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
}
```

But i throws out various errors regardless of what i try, obvious user error.

Can anyone throw me in the right direction on how to parse the example above using JSON.net?

Comment: Your JSON is an array of two totally different objects - JSON.net can't figure out the mapping. You'd have to parse it without a model.

Comment: @LukeBriggs *"You'd have to parse it without a model"*, that is incorrect. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder where you got the Json from, or you just came up with it by yourself. It's not really optimal Json to work with, but since this is *your* example I'l show you how to deserialize it with a mapping model.

#### Mapping

Correct classes (for the Json you provided) to do the mapping on will look like these::

```
public class Item
{
    public int b { get; set; }
    public string Q { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int? seconds_ago { get; set; }
}
```

#### Deserializing:

To deserialize it you use `List<Rootobject>` as the type, since there is more then one root object (because it's an array) `[]`:

```
List<Rootobject> deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(json);
```

Comment: It is a valid JSON and it is optimal if it does contain every information you need. It is just *not optimal* for deserializing into objects, that is true but that is also a different story and you will find it more often *in the wild* as you think

Comment: @SirRufo Considering JSON is *specifically* written to represent objects, one could say if it's not optimal for deserializing into objects, then it's not optimal at all :)

Comment: @Rob Where did you get this from? http://json.org/ talks about objects **and** arrays - and the json from the Q did also just contains objects and arrays - but the array just contains different object types, as you can hold inside a List<object>

Comment: @SirRufo I was just having fun with the fact that JSON stands for javascript object notation - it's designed *specifically* for representing objects. However - you're right in the fact that it's not always optimal for representing a *typed* data structure

Answer (score -2):

here is your solution:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = @"{
    'Property1': [{
        'items': [{
            'b': 1,
            'Q': 'data'
        }, {
            'b': 2,
            'Q': 'more data'
        }],
        'seconds_ago': 1
    }]
}";
        Rootobject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Property1[0].items[0].b);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Property1[0].items[0].Q);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Property1[0].items[1].b);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Property1[0].items[1].Q);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Property1[0].seconds_ago);
    }
}

public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public Item[] items { get; set; }
        public int seconds_ago { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int b { get; set; }
        public string Q { get; set; }
    }
```

You can try it here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/33ZPyX

Problem is mainly structure of your json and your objects. They don't match. Have a look on that fiddle and you should see why.

Comment: Your answer completely changed the structure of the JSON. You've put `seconds_ago` as a property of the object which is holding items.

Comment: What? I mapped the json to match c# classes. How should I know that @Tiago wanted it the other way around? He just says I am trying to deserialize this... I don't get what those down votes are for :(...

Comment: @xszaboj the idea is that you do **not** change the Json that is provided by the OP. Your `data` variable holds a different Json string then the one in the question. So, you ... *changed the structure of the JSON*. Besides ... if you would use the *provided* Json ... the code you demonstrate will throw an error when deserializing.

Comment: @Jim Yes, I agree I've changed the JSON, but I haven't changed the C# object. You just did it other way around....